# How do I run an ASPX file from VS code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, iis

I am trying to learn asp.net but I can't because I am not able to do it practically. I am stuck at the very first step that is to open the aspx file. I have this code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="compare_validator_demo.aspx.cs"   
Inherits="asp.netexample.compare_validator_demo" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  
<title></title>  
<style type="text/css">  
.auto-style1 {  
width: 100%;  
        }  
.auto-style2 {  
height: 26px;  
        }  
.auto-style3 {  
height: 26px;  
width: 93px;  
        }  
.auto-style4 {  
width: 93px;  
        }  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<table class="auto-style1">  
<tr>  
<td class="auto-style3">  
                        First value</td>  
<td class="auto-style2">  
<asp:TextBox ID="firstval" runat="server" required="true"></asp:TextBox>  
</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="auto-style4">  
      Second value</td>  
<td>  
<asp:TextBox ID="secondval" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
       It should be greater than first value</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="auto-style4"></td>  
<td>  
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="save"/>  
</td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="secondval"   
ControlToValidate="firstval" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter valid value" ForeColor="Red"   
Operator="LessThan" Type="Integer"></asp:CompareValidator>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I want to see it live just like an html file. I have tried saving it with an extension compare_validator.aspx
We click a .html file to see the rendered html page on our browser. Does asp files work the same way in vs code or we have to add some configurations? I tried opening it from the finder but it takes me to the vs code. Any type of suggestions would help.

Comment: ASP.Net uses an aspx file extension, rather than asp. The asp extension is only for classic (pre-.Net) asp, and the code sample here is definitely .Net. Also, this code sample is using Web Forms, and while I personally have a certain appreciation for the old web forms technology I wouldn't recommend it as the best option for anyone just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't use Visual Studio, or even Visual code to run a .aspx file.

How Visual Studio works is when you install Visual Studio, then a WHOLE COPY of the IIS web server is also installed. (IIS express is installed).

So, when I am in Visual studio, and I hit f5 to run? While Visual Studio will build and compile the code for the aspx page? Visual studio (or visual code) DOES NOT RUN the aspx page.

The web server loads and runs the page.

What this means is that for aspx pages, you need a valid working and installed web server to view such pages. Visual Studio, or Visual code WILL NOT run the page.

As noted, of course Visual Studio does setup and run IIS for you, but do keep the above important distinction in mind. Visual Studio can "launch" your aspx page during development, but to do that magic trick, VS in fact starts a copy of the web server (IIS express), and then has the web server consume, load, and interpret the aspx page. So, once again, Visual Studio (or visual code) does not, and can not, and will not run that aspx page. You need a working and installed web server running that can consume + run + launch that aspx page....

So, it looks like say this when I hit f5 in Visual studio to run that page:

[image]

So, in most cases you can NOT run an aspx page. And in fact, the aspx page in most cases MUST BE PART of a working web project. Since a web server and the correct configuration is required for such web pages, then even the concept of having IIS or Visual Studio (or Visual code) run/launch a single aspx page in most cases cannot be done. In other words, you FIRST create a working web project, and then add that ONE page to the working site. You can then have as above screen video shows VS launch the page.

So, in most cases, a web site with configuration is required before you attempt to run/use/consume/play with/design the aspx page. The concept of that page just being run thus does not really exist. You need to setup a working web site project FIRST, and then such aspx pages can be used and run. They don't run stand alone, and in fact in most cases not even Visual Studio can launch and hand off a page to IIS.

But, make no mistake here, Visual Studio, or Visual code does not and can not and will not run the .aspx page for you. You need a working web site server setup and running for such pages to be viewed on your computer.

So, to try your above web page? Well, what you posted so far is missing the code behind file, and that would be required.

So, what I could "try" here is to in one of my existing working projects (note VERY careful here - I stated I going to use a EXISTING project, since aspx pages can't and don't exist nor run as stand alone).

so, lets create a new blank web page.

I get this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm9.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSharpWebApp.WebForm9" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>



        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what I could do then is take your "stuff" from the form part of the page and past it in.

Note how I do not (and can not) mess around with all of the parts of the page created by the desinger. So, the top most part of the page, I used my settings and let Visual Studio create the parts of the page for me. I can thus with your shared information so far ONLY dump in the content between the form tag.

So, I now have this:

[image]

Of course without the code behind, and the other parts of this page that are missing, then you can't run the code. So, a web page has the markup part and also has a code behind part. Both of these bits and parts are required to run such a web page. As pointed out, in most cases, you need to FIRST setup a working site site application in VS, and then add the page in question to the project. As noted, often it is better to let visual studio create/add the web page, and then you grab the markup (between the form tag) and paste that into a new page.

The reason I suggest the above, is that Visual Studio/Code goes though quite a complex set of rules to add a new web page to a existing project, and in most cases you need/require VS to add the web page, not just to copy some existing web page into that web project.